# Código JSP de scriptlet para EL

Tags: java, jsp

Como posso reescrever esse código JSP utilizando Expression Language?

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>



    <%

        int tipoForma;
        String tituloFormulario, headerFormulario;


        if (request.getParameter("formas") != null){
            tipoForma = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("formas"));
        }else{
            tipoForma = 0;
        }


        if (tipoForma == 1){
            tituloFormulario = "<img src='img/quadrado.jpg'/> <p>Calculando área do Quadrado </p>";
            headerFormulario = "<form action='calc-quadrado.jsp'/>"; 

        }else if (tipoForma == 2){
            tituloFormulario = "<p>Calculando área do Triângulo </p>";
            headerFormulario = "<form action='calc-triangulo.jsp'/>";

        }else if (tipoForma == 3){
            tituloFormulario = "<p>Calculando área da Circunferencia </p>";
            headerFormulario = "<form action='calc-circunferencia.jsp'/>";
        }else{
            tituloFormulario = "***Erro***";
            headerFormulario = "<form action='calc-triangulo.jsp'/>";
        }

        out.println(headerFormulario);

    %>

    <h2><%=tituloFormulario%></h2>

    <%if (tipoForma == 1){%>
        <input name="lado" placeholder="Digite o valor do lado">
    <%}else if (tipoForma == 2){%>
        <input name="base" placeholder="Digite o valor do base">
        <input name="lado" placeholder="Digite o valor do altura">
    <%}else if (tipoForma == 3){%>
        <input name="base" placeholder="Digite o raio">
    <%}else{%>
        <%=tituloFormulario%>
    <%}%>



    <input type="submit" value="Calcular">




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, eu recomendo o uso de UTF-8 ao invés de ISO-8859-1. O mundo inteiro está unificando e universalizando tudo ao redor do UTF-8 porque ele tem a vantagem de poder codificar quaisquer caracteres em quaisquer línguas sem problemas, inclusive misturando caracteres de grupos totalmente dissimilares tais como chinês e hebraico e é reconhecido e aceito por quase todos os sistemas de codificação de caracteres modernos. Além disso, o seu formato é bem próximo ao formato nativo no qual strings são armazenadas em Java. Ele é capaz inclusive de codificar emojis ().

No entanto, se não quiser usar UTF-8, tudo bem. Apenas certifique-se de salvar o seu arquivo JSP com a mesma codificação que ele é servido.

Também tenha cuidado com o formato do HTML que é injetado na página. Colocar tags `<img>` e `<p>` dentro de tags `<h2>` não é uma boa ideia. Felizmente, a própria substituição de scriptlets por JSP puro deve te ajudar bastante a resolver-se esse problema. O tag `<c:choose>` deve te ajudar:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Cálculo de área</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 1}">
                <form action='calc-quadrado.jsp'>
                    <img src='img/quadrado.jpg' />
                    <h2>Calculando área do Quadrado</h2>
                    <input name="lado" placeholder="Digite o valor do lado" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />
                </form>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 2}">
                <form action='calc-triangulo.jsp'>
                    <h2>Calculando área do Triângulo</h2>
                    <input name="base" placeholder="Digite o valor do base" />
                    <input name="altura" placeholder="Digite o valor do altura" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />
                </form>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 3}">
                <form action='calc-circunferencia.jsp'>
                    <h2>Calculando área da Circunferência</h2>
                    <input name="raio" placeholder="Digite o raio" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />
                </form>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <form action=''>
                    <h2>***Erro***</h2>
                </form>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </body>
</html>
```

Caso você considere tudo isso muito repetitivo, ao repetir-se diversos trechos de HTML em diferentes `<c:when>`s, você pode setar diversas variáveis nos `<c:when>`s usando `<c:set>` e usá-las depois com `<c:if>`, `<c:url>` e `<c:out>`:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Cálculo de área</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 1}">
                <c:set var="target" value="calc-quadrado.jsp" />
                <c:set var="img" value="img/quadrado.jpg" />
                <c:set var="titulo" value="Calculando área do Quadrado" />
                <c:set var="campo1" value="lado" />
                <c:set var="descricao1" value="Digite o valor do lado" />
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 2}">
                <c:set var="target" value="calc-triangulo.jsp" />
                <c:set var="titulo" value="Calculando área do Triângulo" />
                <c:set var="campo1" value="base" />
                <c:set var="descricao1" value="Digite o valor da base" />
                <c:set var="campo2" value="altura" />
                <c:set var="descricao2" value="Digite o valor da altura" />
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${param.formas == 3}">
                <c:set var="target" value="calc-circunferencia.jsp" />
                <c:set var="titulo" value="Calculando área da Circunferência" />
                <c:set var="campo1" value="raio" />
                <c:set var="descricao1" value="Digite o valor do raio" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="titulo" value="***Erro***" />
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

        <form action='<c:url value="${target}" />>
            <c:if test="${img}"><img src='<c:url value="${img}" />' /></c:if>
            <h2><c:out value="${titulo}" /></h2>
            <c:if test="${campo1}"><input name="<c:out value="${campo1}" />" placeholder="<c:out value="${descricao1}" />" /></c:if>
            <c:if test="${campo2}"><input name="<c:out value="${campo2}" />" placeholder="<c:out value="${descricao2}" />" /></c:if>
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ah, e certifique-se sempre que as suas tags HTML fiquem bem formadas. Os `<input>`s só vão funcionar se estiverem dentro do `<form>`.